# How to write parameter one recommend Endpoint To Database in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm newbie in Angular. I have a database includes movies and actors, and one recommend endpoint url. 
I want to recommend something for each elements( movies and actors) when I send request to recommend endpoint by ID. I think I need to use HttpParams but how.  Anyone help ?

Edit:
 I want to clearify this.

I have one database(http://travis.com:3002/db/commit)
 and one recommend url ( http://10.10.10.10:2999/getMostSimilar?model_id = 1232321455&numSimilar=10%uri=neo4j://individuals/1)... 
I send request to recommend url to recommend  uri for each element in the database object by id which have an id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
const params = new HttpParams();
params.set('one', '1')
params.set('two', '2');
this.httpClient.get("/api/countries", {params})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily *need* `HttpParams` to make a request via `HttpClient`.

The simplest way is just to form the url:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getMovie(id): Observable<Movie> {
  const url = `https://mydatabase.com/movies?id=${id}`; // multiline strings (``)
  return this.http.get<Movie>(url);
}
```

Where `Movie` is some interface you have created with properties that match your endpoint's response.

Edit:

If you want to use `HttpParams`, you can do the following:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getMovie(id): Observable<Movie> {
  const url = 'https://mydatabase.com/movies';
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('id', id);
  return this.http.get<Movie>(url, { params });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help;
But I want to clearify this. 
 I have one database(http://travis.com:3002/db/commit)
 and one recommend url ( http://10.10.10.10:2999/getMostSimilar?model_id = 1232321455&numSimilar=10%uri=neo4j://individuals/1)... 
I send request to recommend url to recommend  uri for each element in the database object by id which have an id.